# Are the source codes of Node.js desktop applications protected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I am planning to create a Node.js desktop application. I am concerned if I write the application in javascript, the source code of it might not be secured just like scripts served on web browsers. Is it possible to secure both server-side script and client-side script including css when building a Node.js desktop application?

Comment: Node.js is server-side, so it's secured, the client side however is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you want to protect your JS source code - short answer is NOT all of the JavaScript File's source code will be safe.

Tools Kit like [NW.js](http://nwjs.io//) helps to protect JS file to some extent. Depends on how the JavaScript Files are used in your application.

Read about packaging Application using NW.js here

- http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Package%20and%20Distribute/#package-your-app

And Protecting JS Files is documented in below link

- http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Protect%20JavaScript%20Source%20Code/

Since you said you are in planning stage- you can also select Electron, which allows to create Application Package

- http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-packaging/

Comment: What do you mean by "NOT all of the Javscript file's source code will be safe"? Could you elaborate little more?

Comment: When you will create package, some of the JS files can still remain as Plain JS files. I had updated my answer, try to follow the provided link.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the production closed-source Electron / NodeJS based desktop applications have their source code concatenated ( using [webpack](http://webpack.github.io) e.g. ), minified & [uglified](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS).

CSS can also be protected via technique such as [CSSModules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).

If your application is React based, you practically include all of the HTML / DOM elements inside your JavaScript, so it doesn't need any additional protection.

By doing this you are very close to what a normally compiled C++ / ObjectiveC app will give you when you debug it.